# How to hide Bootstrap alert box when no message

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a simple alert box with Bootstrap like this

```
<div class="alertBox">
     <span role="alert" class="alert alert-info"> bag.session.username </span>
</div>
```

When there is no alert (box is empty), the box still shows on the page like this. [image]

So I tried to hide it when it's empty with [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (bag.session.username) {
        $(".alertBox").show();
    }
    else {
        $(".alertBox").hide();
    }
});
</script>
```

This basically says if an alert message is there, show the box, if not, hide it. However, this does not work as expected. The box is there until there is no alert. How can I solve this?

Comment: Where is this `bag.session.username` coming from?

Comment: Slightly off-topic: In your HTML, are you trying to print out some JS variable called `bag.session.username`?  Because what you've got is just the text `bag.session.username`.

Comment: Interestingly that his box is empty, it should contain bag.session.username

Comment: @MarkoMackic for my app, I have it so that the username could be empty string in some cases, therefore the solution where it checks that it is undefined solved my issue. Thanks

Comment: @OneMoreQuestion that's wrong my friend , undefined variables are not good to be in app ,you can init it with null, or '' and then safely check

Comment: @MarkoMackic I agree, will try to change this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to initially hide your alert box. Also it looks like your putting a JavaScript variable right into your HTML. Also the string bag.session.username may always evaluate to true. Maybe this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (typeof bag.session.username != "undefined") {
        $(".alertBox span").text(bag.session.username);
        $(".alertBox").show();
    }
    else {
        $(".alertBox").hide();
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks this worked for me, by the way the var is not in my HTML, these are just snippets

Comment: @OneMoreQuestion I don't have enough rep to comment on the above. I don't think there is any problem with checking if a var is undefined. It wouldn't make sense to go through each bag.session var that could possibly be set and set it to null.

Comment: in this case checking for undefined is good because it includes ckecking for null and empty strings as well as undefined

Comment: That's why I selected this answer

Answer (score 1):

> The below code should help you solve your problem. Let me know if you have any questions

```
<style>
        .foo{
            display: none;
        }
</style>
```

> HTML and JS will be

```
<body>
    <div class="alertBox">
        <span role="alert" class="alert alert-info"></span>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("span.alert").each(function(){
                if(!$(this).text().trim().length){
                    $(".alertBox").addClass("foo");
                }
            })

        });
```