# How to hide bootstrap alert if it has no content?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap alert that's supposed to hide if there's no text inside it. I was able to make the alert not take up the whole screen, but what's left is this small piece of it on top of the page. I've been trying out this code that I found here ([How to hide Bootstrap alert box when no message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38621130/how-to-hide-bootstrap-alert-box-when-no-message)) but this happened.[image]

Here's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (<%= notice %>.length != 0) {
    $("#notice span").text(<%= notice %>);
    $("#notice").show();
}
else {
    $("#notice").hide();
}
});
</script>

<div id="notice" style="text-align: center;">
<span role="alert" class="alert alert-success">
<%= notice %>
</span>
</div>
```

Edit: <% notice %> is the alert text, #notice is the id of the div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply this without `jQuery` you don't need jQuery for this like below

```
<% if notice.present? %>
  <div id="notice" style="text-align: center;">
    <span role="alert" class="alert alert-success">
        <%= notice %>
    </span>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

You can this class dynamic e.g `alert`, `notice`, `success`, `danger` like if your controller flash is

```
flash[:alert] = 'Model was successfully created.'
or
flash[:notice] = 'Model was successfully created.'
or
flash[:success] = 'Model was successfully created.'
or
flash[:danger] = 'Model was successfully created.'
```

now your flash section will be

```
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
    <div id="notice" style="text-align: center;">
        <span role="alert" class="alert alert-<%="#{name}" %>">
        <p><%= msg if msg.is_a?(String) %></p>
    </span>
<% end %>
```

That's it.

Hope will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    if ($('#notice>span').html().length>0) {
      $("#notice").show();
    } else {
      $("#notice").hide();
    }
  });
</script>
```

You don't need to set the value from javascript, `<%= notice %>` will print it to the view.

Comment: Tried this, the alert won't show after I click the button that's supposed to show it.

Comment: @thepersonwho which button?